# How to project filtered array's element in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

The following MongoDB document has array of `workflow` element. The root document has `_id` and also each workflow has unique `_id`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54aedb94e6c12b1c0e83385f"), //root id
    "name" : "somename",
    "workflows" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Workflow1",            
            "_id" : ObjectId("54aedb94e6c12b1c0e83394c"),
            "taskGroups" : [ 
                {
                    "processingPhase" : "PHASE1",                    
                    "_id" : ObjectId("555b62f89a2582000e360cff")                    
                }, 
                {
                    "processingPhase" : "PHASE2",                    
                    "_id" : ObjectId("555b62f89a2582000e360cc2"),
                }, 
                {
                    "processingPhase" : "PHASE3",                    
                    "_id" : ObjectId("555b62f89a2582000e360c80"),
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Workflow2",            
            "_id" : ObjectId("54aedb94e6c12b1c0e83389e"),
            "taskGroups" : [ 
                {
                    "processingPhase" : "PHASE1",                    
                    "_id" : ObjectId("555b63169a2582000e360d8e")           
                }, 
                {
                    "processingPhase" : "PHASE2",                    
                    "_id" : ObjectId("555b63169a2582000e360d51")
                }, 
                {
                    "processingPhase" : "PHASE3",                    
                    "_id" : ObjectId("555b63169a2582000e360d0f")
                }
            ]
        }, 
    ],
    "__v" : 54
}
```

Given root document's _id and workflow's _id, i wanted to select single workflow and project its `taskGroups` child.

```
public void SelectTaskGroups(string rootid,string workflowid)
{
    var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
       .Include("workflows.taskGroups");
    var filterBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
    var filter = filterBuilder.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(rootid)) &
        filterBuilder.Eq("workflows._id", ObjectId.Parse(workflowid));
    var tg = await clientCollection
        .Find(filter)
        .Project(projection)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

however the C# code above projects the entire document. I only wanted to project `taskGroups` element of filtered `workgroup`

Comment: Try `workflows.$.taskGroups` in the projection. Positional operator to pick array by index.

Comment: @SagarReddy That solved my issue. Thanks